# Changes to transitive dependencies not triggering live reload

Tags: stylus, livereload, snowpack

I've added Snowpack 3 to my application and it works for JS/TS files as well as directly imported stylus files.

The file structure is similar to the following:

**view.js:**

```
import 'view-styles.styl'

export default function view() {
    return (
        <div className='example-view'>Hello World</div>
    );
}
```

**view-styles.styl**

```
@require './colors.styl'
.example-view
    background-color: $mainColor
```

**colors.styl**

```
$mainColor = #ff0000
```

The LiveReload/HMR works as expected when changing the directly imported stylus file. It does not work when changing anything in the colors.styl file. Changes in this file are only picked up once the view-styles.styl file is updated.

Is this a known limitation of Snowpack?

I would also be ok to trigger the update manually, as I have a way to identify these files using their filenames. I haven't found a way yet to trigger live reloads using Snowpack's JavaScript API. I was able to load the file using the SnowpackDevServer.loadUrl function, but that doesn't help either.

Comment: I am not conversant with the Stylus language. You can however explore adding [`buildOptions.watch`](https://www.snowpack.dev/reference/configuration#buildoptions.watch) to the _snowpack.config.js_ file.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to contribute this to the snowpack stylus plugin. The change was already integrated into the plugin: https://github.com/fansenze/snowpack-plugin-stylus